# How can I target the tbody of a specific Div?

Tags: html, css-tables

I have a table that I'd like to target with CSS.  The table is inside a div called inner1b

```
inner1b.tbody{
display:block;
height:800px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

doesn't seem to be working

Comment: `div > table > tbody`

Comment: `.` is CSS selectof for class. Do you target a class ? No => You shouldn't have a `.` in your selector. The selector you're showing would target a `inner1b` tag with a `tbody` class. In other words, it is totally wrong.

Comment: Well, not totally. 

Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inner1b` does not have a `.` or a `#`, so your rule is looking for `<inner1b class="tbody">`, which isn't a valid HTML tag. You need to do

```
.inner1b table tbody {
...
}
```

Comment: Got it, makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
.inner1b tbody { ... }
```

Your mistake was connecting the two selectors, which implies a single element. The dot was also out of place.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
  .inner1b table tbody {
    display:block;
    height:800px;
    overflow:auto;
  }
</style>
```